# four the shortest sequences vs four shortest sequences

Tags: sentence-usage

Is this sentence correct?

"we decided to fold only four the shortest sequences"

(it's a scientific text)

or "four shortest" should be used instead?

Comment: The first example is nonsense.

Comment: You mean _the four shortest_, surely?

Comment: What is this sentence supposed to mean? What have you looked up? Even searching for a phrase in Google will provide some research (Ngrams might be better). "Is this sentence correct?" is proofreading unless you can say **why** you are asking. Note that does not include "or is this better?" -- you have to say what it is about your sentence which has caused you to doubt yourself.

Comment: It needs to be (1) *only four **of** the shortest sequences* or (2) *only **the four shortest** sequences*.